# Running Selenium TestNG scripts with batch file

Tags: selenium, batch-file, webdriver, testng

I am trying to run my sample `Selenium WebDriver` and `TestNG` script from command prompt. I could run it with **Eclipse>Run As>TestNG Suite** and getting the expected output. However, if I run the same test script from the command prompt, the test fails without any error message with the following output:

```
C:\Gopal\jenkinsInt>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Gopal\jenkinsInt\testng.xml

Jenkins integration

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

The console output in Eclipse is:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Gopal\jenkinsInt\testng.xml

Jenkins integration
Google
===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

My sample script is:

```
package jenkinsDemo;

public class jenkinsJob {   
  @Test     
  public void testJenkins() {
    System.out.println("Jenkins integration");      
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");      
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());  
    driver.quit();  
 }  

}
```

Comment: `Failures: 1` what do you have in the reports? Could you share them?

Answer (score 0):

`TestNG` is running and your `@Test` method (i.e. `testJenkins()`) is failing. The root cause of failure can be seen in `TestNG` reports.

Running `testng.xml` from command prompt, is printing `Jenkins integration` but not `Google`. So it's clear that your test method logic starts execution but because of `Selenium` stuffs it is failing.

**Solution:**
You need to make sure along with `TestNG`, `Selenium` is also in you `classpath`.
For more information and example on the same you can check [execute selenium test from command line](http://learn-automation.com/execute-selenium-test-from-command-line/).

Comment: Thanks Atul for the solution. I downloaded the selenium again and updated the library and its working fine now.